# Facebook Customer Chat showing empty iframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

i'm tried to include Facebook Customer Chat and test it on localhost. But all i see is empty iframe.

I doesn't have any errors just an empty iframe with . Also it doesn't react to FB.CustomerChat.show();

Some key moments from my code:

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";`

````
Vue.use(vue_fb, {
        appId: process.env.FACEBOOK_AUTH_APP_ID,
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v4.0'
    });```
````

Comment: I don’t think you can test this on `localhost`; the requirements for white-listing your domain can’t be fulfilled with that - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting#requirements You’ll need to set up a fully qualified domain name for testing, and make it available via HTTPS as well. (Maybe consider ngrok as an option fpr local testing.)

Comment: @misorude i have got an error with "content policy", then i used google chrome extension to prevent this error, it is disappeared but it's shows only empty iframe.

Comment: Are you using a different domain name now? Have you already gone through the troubleshooting tips the manual offers?

Comment: @misorude i'm using https://192.168.0.8:3000 it's still localhost but with fake ssl. I guess.

Comment: As I said, I’d suggest looking into ngrok to be able to perform tests like this with less hassle.

Comment: @misorude okay, lemme try.

Comment: @misorude yoooo, thanks. You can post it as an answer, so i can give you a star ))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` won’t work for testing of this plugin, because of the requirements for white-listing the domain, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting#requirements:

> Domains must meet the following requirements to be whitelisted:
>   - Served over HTTPS
>   - Use a fully qualified domain name, such as https://www.messenger.com/. IP addresses and localhost are not supported for whitelisting.

A locally set up domain name with a self-signed certificate should probably work - all the relevant stuff happens in the browser, so that’s the only one you’d have to convince to accept that self-signed certificate.

But it’s probably a better option not to deal with the hassle of issuing and embedding your own certificate - and use a service like https://ngrok.com/ instead, that provides an easy HTTPS tunnel to your localhost, which is ideally suited to test stuff like this.